# Model to correspond to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application where I have three models: *Table*, *Column*, and *Row*. They look like this:

Table:

```
has_many :columns
accepts_nested_attributes_for :columns
```

Column:

```
belongs_to :table
has_many :rows

accepts_nested_attributes_for :rows, :reject_if => lambda { |b| b[:data].blank? }
```

Row:

```
belongs_to :column
```

I'm trying to make a table like the one I described in a previous answer: [Creating a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748099/creating-a-spreadsheet). To implement it, I have two controllers: a TablesController, and a RowsController (The Rows Controller should probably be called something different because it contains both rows and columns). I have nested routes, so you can visit /tables/1/rows and it will show you the columns that are associated with the 1st table.

Here's the code:

```
@columns = Column.where(:table_id => @table.id)
@rows = Row.all
```

and:

```
<% @columns.each do |column| %>
  <% @rows.each do |row| %>
     Column name:<%= column.name %><br>
     Row data: <%= row.data %><br>
    <hr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, the rows are returning ALL of the results in the entire database. But I can't figure out how to get them to correspond to the column they are with?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your controller code from:

```
@columns = Column.where(:table_id => @table.id)
@rows = Row.all
```

to:

```
@columns = Column.where(:table_id => @table.id)
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @columns.each do |column| %>
  <% column.rows.each do |row| %>
     Column name:<%= column.name %><br>
     Row data: <%= row.data %><br>
    <hr />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Because you have `@rows = Rows.all`, it is going to return all the rows in `rows` table.  To retrieve `rows` for a particular `column` you would do `column.rows`.